# Strategy for detecting (via Reflection) if Enum is of type "Flags" in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, reflection

I'm using Reflection to read types inside an assembly (to generate code). I can see that some enumerations should have been marked with the `[Flags]` attribute but whoever wrote those enums forgot to add this attribute.

Is there any reliable way of detecting when an enum can be considered a "Flags" enum?

My strategy at the moment is to read the enum in descending order, and checking if the value of element(last -1) * 2 == element(last).

That works great in most cases, except when I have enums with 0, 1, and 2 values (which could be flags or not).

---

edit:

Example of an enum that I'd like to detect as being flags:

```
public enum EnumIsFlag1
{
    ItemA = 2,
    ItemB = 4,
    ItemC = ItemA + ItemB,
    ItemD = 32,
    ItemE = 64,
}
```

---

edit: **My question is not a duplicate... The moderator clearly didn't read my question**

Comment: Wouldn't you check that `element(last-1) * 2 == element(last)`?

Comment: `[Flags]` just helps the compiler choose appropriate values for the enumeration (typically when they are not specified). Any Enum that has bit-shifted values can be considered appropriate for being used as flags.

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm pretty certain that the `[Flags]` attribute is only really used when formatting the enum value as a string: it has no bearing on the enum member values assigned by the compiler. The second part of your comment is correct however.

Comment: What about if you have some combination? e.g. `enum Permissions { Read, Write, Both = Read | Write }`.

Comment: @StevenRands Seems you are right. I always thought it would bit-shift values but after running a test it looks like it doesn't. Usually I specify the values so I don't run into it myself.

Comment: I think using the [Flags] attribute also causes the "HasFlag" method to appear as a method on the enum.  Any code to do this is going to require some level of assumption.  Why would you not just mark the enum as [Flags] as you find it.  If you are trying to modify an enum from a class library, then I would be cautious trying to modify behavior of code that you cannot see.  Even if it appears obvious that the enum should have been "flags" that doesn't mean the code will properly treat the passed enum values as such.

Comment: @MikeU No, the flags attribute does not cause that method to appear, its there regardless of the flags attribute.

Comment: That's fair.  Never looked for it on an enum I hadn't marked :)

Comment: @WaiHaLee `Permissions.Both` results in *Write*. Either you leave out the assignment, in which case it isn't a proper flag, or you assign proper bit values to the fields.

Comment: @IllidanS4 - good spot. I meant to assign values of 1 and 2 to `Read` and `Write`, in which case `Both` is 3.

Comment: Yes Marc, that is what I currently do. I fixed the question. Thanks

Comment: Ron, that is OK... I just want to (with some certainty) decide if Flags is appropriate or not. I'm generating code from reading metadata and want to put the [Flags] attribute on the generated code if I have enough confidence that it makes sense

Comment: Why do you want to detect this? I cant think of any pracitcal benefit of detecting stuff like this at runtime? Only for some codefix tool or similiar.

disregard this comment, you answered in the same moment.

Comment: Hava you tried to use Roslyn? For what you are doing I would choose it. With Roslyn you could check if this **ItemC = ItemA + ItemB** happens.

Comment: Alberto, I cannot use Roslyn. The code that I am generating is .NET (C#), but the metadata that I'm reading is not .NET code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, this problem can only be solved heuristically but I understand that's what you are after.

Typically, flags enums have most members with a single bit set. So I would count the number of members that have only a single bit set (e.g. that are a power of two).

Then, you can devise a heuristic such as:

```
//Is this a flags enum?

var totalCount = ...;
var powerOfTwoCount = ...;

if (totalCount < 3) return false; //Can't decide.
if (powerOfTwoCount >= totalCount * 0.95) return true; //Looks like flags
//Probably need some cases for small values of totalCount.
```

The only reason multiple bits could be set in a legitimate flags enum is combinations of flags. But the number of such enum items is usually small.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I'm looking for (heuristics). This works well for perfect flags where all values are power of two, but doesn't work when there are combinations... (added example to my answer)

Comment: What do you think about the heuristic part where I talk about combinations of flags? Clearly, this is impossible to solve in general because every possible number is a combination of some bits.

Comment: I have no doubts that this is the way to go about this problem... What I am struggling with is how to develop a heuristic that is good. Changing the 0.95 to a lower value will give me lots of false positives so I think this needs some tweaking... Possibly a few iterations asking different questions (?)

Comment: I had one more idea. It can't be a flags enum if there exists a value that is multi-bit and is not a combination of existing single bit values. This should be quite common. For example almost all sequences [0,N] do not fall under that category. And almost all non-flags enums are sequences like that.

Comment: Any chance you can update your answer with some code - even pseudo-code?

Comment: I'd first determine the bits that are covered by single bit constants. Simply take all single bit constants and | them together. Then, every multi bit constant that has bits outside of those blessed bits is invalid.

Comment: "determine the bits that are covered by single bit constants"  - how do I do that? I'm not familiar with bit shifting... I just know how to use the flags using sum, etc.

Comment: OK, Google for how to determine whether an integer has a single bit set. You should be able to piece this together since, I think, the general idea is clear. Feel free to ask further concrete follow up questions.

Comment: I didn't get very far... I can check which items in the enum are a power of 2 (which I think means they have 1 bit set) but can't tell when they have more than one bit set... Marking it as an answer because ideas were helpful, but would appreciate a more concrete example if you can.

Comment: `can't tell when they have more than one bit set` ??? You know how to test for one bit. So anything else has either zero bits or multiple! What about `!ispoweroftwo(x) && x != 0`?

Comment: Combinations sometimes are not a power of 2... But still valid

Comment: Combinations *never* are a power of two.

Comment: "every multi bit constant that has bits outside of those blessed bits is invalid" -> How do I translate this to code?

Comment: bessedBits & constant != 0 I would say.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8480) goes into detail about the differences between the two, and they are very minor: just some string formatting behaviour.

The strict answer to your question is that any type can be checked for the flags enum using reflection. Anything else just needs to be checked by a human. You can check for the Flags attribute directly like this;

```
[Flags]
enum Foo
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 4
}

enum Bar
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 4
}


bool IsFlagsEnum(Type t) 
{
    var attr = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FlagsAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
    var result = attr != null;
    return result;
}

Console.WriteLine(IsFlagsEnum(typeof(Foo))); // True
Console.WriteLine(IsFlagsEnum(typeof(Bar))); // False
```

Comment: "I can see that some enumerations should have been marked with the [Flags] attribute but whoever wrote those enums forgot to add this attribute." did you read the question?

Comment: Yes. There is no algorithm to detect whether an enum should be flags. Both flags and non-flags can contain the same values and a sequence like { 0,1,2,4,8 } doesn't imply a flags enum any more than { 0,1,2,3,4 } implies non-flags. Both are valid either way. All you can do is review the code and decide the meaning for yourself. This code reliably detects, via reflection, if an enum is Flags.

Comment: It does reliably detect if the enum has been *marked* as [Flags], but not if the enum should have been marked, which is what the question is actually about.

Comment: Steve, you misunderstood my question... The attribute is not there so I want to "guess" if the attribute should have been there

Comment: @Lindsay1986 well, that's not something a program can answer. Flags and not-flags can be used in the same way, are numbered the same way, and really only vary by the behaviour of ToString(). A flags enum often has contiguous values like { 0 1 2 3 4 } because it's useful to name the combinations. Maybe you could [use Roslyn to detect if there are any bitwise operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx)  using the enum type, but that feels heavy! But it's the only operation that flags are designed for.

Comment: Steve, I am aware that a program will not be able to detect with 100% accuracy, but I'm looking for high probability. I cannot use Roslyn because the metadata that I'm reading is not .NET - the code that I am generating is .NET (C#).